# @lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'AnyObject in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have a custom TableViewCell which has a label and a button. I have an Int array `groupVote` which holds the values that will populate the labels `voteScoreLabel` in the `UITableView`.  When the button, `upVoteButtonPressed` is tapped, the corresponding value to the cell is updated using the tag. However in the following code there is an error (I have put the specific line in the following code) which displays: @lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'AnyObject!, when I want to update the value in Parse. What does it mean, and how can I fix it?

```
@IBAction func upVoteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag])
    groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]=groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]+1
  var messageDisplayTwo = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
    messageDisplayTwo.whereKey("identifier", equalTo:voteScoreLabel.tag )
    messageDisplayTwo.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            for object in objects {
                var textNumb=groupVote[self.voteScoreLabel.tag] as Int
                object["vote"]=textNumb //Error Right Here: @lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'AnyObject!


            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `for object in objects as [NSDictionary] {`.

Comment: @vacawama I just tried that and got the error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `objects` to an array of `PFObject`.

```
for object in objects as [PFObject] {
        var textNumb = groupVote[self.voteScoreLabel.tag] as Int
        object["vote"] = textNumb
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


            if (error == nil) {
                // objects in results will only contain the playerName and score fields

                for object in objects as [PFObject] {
...
...
```